# Monotouch Dialog partially hidden behind IOS 7 top navigation bar and clock

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios7, monotouch.dialog

Just started targetting IOS 7 with Xamarin Studio but now my monotouch dialog views are partially hidden behind top navigation bar and clock.

How to reveal them/resize view/fix?

Answer (score 1):

Although adding a padding to the top will fix your problem, maybe the best thing to do is use the Property that Xamarin provides just for this issue:

```
EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
```

You can set this in the `ViewDidLoad()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding a top padding. The simplest way of adding this padding is to take advantage of the Section headers and footers.

```
var margin = new UIView (new RectangleF (0, 65, 1, 200)); //200 View Height, 65 Margin Top
var section = new Section (margin);
```

In that section you add your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Except if you're using a UINavigationController, the top bar is now part of the screen estate you have to use.
If you want your app to be compatible in ios 6 and 7, there's some delta you can set in IB